# No puedo hacer "push" desde Git

Tags: git, github

Quiero mandar mi código hacia mi repositorio remoto pero tengo problema al momento de hacer **push** desde mi consola de **Git**.

Una vez que ya tengo todo agregado ingreso mi *clave https*:
`git remote add origin https://github.com/...`
posteriormente ya es necesario hacer **push** entonces ingreso:
`git push origin master`
pero me sale lo siguiente acompañado de un error:

> To https://github.com/myUser/myRepo.git
>    ! [rejected]        master -> master (fetch first)
>   error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/...'
>   hint: Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do
>   hint: not have locally. This is usually caused by another repository pushing
>   hint: to the same ref. You may want to first integrate the remote changes
>   hint: (e.g., 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
>   hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.

me dice que no lo tengo localmente, asi es que puse:
`git remote --v`
para ver si estaba apuntando al *repo remoto* (ya que no se me ocurría alguna solución) y efectivamente estaba apuntando a él.
No me deja pasar de *local* a *remoto* mi código.

Alguien sabe qué pasa o qué estoy haciendo mal?
Espero puedan ayudarme. Muchas Gracias.

Comment: primero prueba con hacer `git pull` para nivelar la rama local con la remota y hay si puedes hacer `push`

Comment: si apliqué `git pull`  pero salía:  
_fatal: refusing to merge unrelated histories_  
pero ya quedó resuelto el problema, abajo repondo qué es lo que apliqué. Muchas Gracias.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Como te dice el mensaje de error esto sucede en general porque el código que tienes en local en tu repositorio difiere del código que está en el repositorio remoto. Primero tienes que actualizar tu repositorio local para contemplar los cambios (`commits`) que se han producido en el remoto, arreglar los conflictos y luego te permitirá subir el código.

Un par de apuntos a mayores:

- Si te has bajado el repo con un `git clone` no debería ser necesario que hagas un `git remote add` a mano ya debería estar configurado.
- El `git remote add` se suele emplear cuando creas un repositorio local de git en el que vas añadiendo cambios. A continuación creas un repositorio vacío remoto en GitHub o cualquier otro servidor. Y quieres subir tu código local al repo remoto. En este caso *inicial* nunca te debería dar problemas hacer el `push`
- En muy contadas ocasiones te puede interesar "sobreescribir" los cambios remotos directamente con lo que hay en tu repo local. Si no estás muy seguro de para que vale esto y de por qué lo necesitas no deberías hacerlo. En todo caso el comando sería `git push -f referencia_remota referencia_local`
- Una de las posibles formas de trabajar en git, para evitar problemas sería siguiendo este flujo:

  1. Descargo el repo con `git clone`
  2. Creo una rama local en la que trabajo `git checkout -b mi_rama_local` y voy añadiendo commits a esa rama, hasta que la feature o el bug está resuelto.
  3. Vas a `master` con `git checkout master` y te traes los posibles cambios que haya en remoto `git pull`
  4. Vas a la rama local con `git checkout mi_rama_local` e integras en ella los nuevos cambios de master con `git rebase master`. Esto metería los cambios en master por debajo de tus cambios actuales por decirlo de alguna forma. Esto evita los commits vacíos de "merge". A algunos equipos le gustan tener esos commits para saber cuando se integro y a otros no. A mi particularmente me resultan molestos. por eso lo hago así.
  5. Si hay algún conflicto lo resuelves
  6. Cambias a master y te traes los cambios de la rama local `git merge mi_rama_local`
  7. Subes los cambios `git push origin master`

Si has estado trabajando en master directamente, lo que alguna gente considera una mala práctica, puedes intentar traerte los cambios remotos directamente por debajo de tus cambios locales con `git pull --rebase`, resolver los conflictos y hacer `git push`

Comment: Muchas gracias por la ayuda, buena información. Lo que _me sirvió_ fue `git push -f  referencia_remota referencia_local`, primero quise intentar nuevamente con `git push` pero seguía saliendo el error, así es que intenté agregando `-f` y fue el comando que me ayudo a empujar mis cambios al repositorio remoto.

Answer (score 4):

Simplemente necesitas hacer pull antes de hacer push, por si hubiera algún conflicto corregirlo antes de subir lo tuyo.

---

Metodología cuando empiezas git.

- Git status  -> Mirar si tienes modificaciones tuyas y si existe algún pull o push
- Git fetch   -> Por si acaso tus ramas no se han actualizado correctamente, esto NO actualiza los ficheros de las ramas, sólo el estado de esa rama
- Git status  -> Para verificar de nuevo modificaciones, pull y pushs
- Git pull    -> Ahora sí descargas las actualizaciones
- Git add/commit/... -> Ahora guardas tus modificaciones
- Git status -> Miras que siga sin necesitar un pull, por si las moscas
- Git push   -> Subes tus datos
- Git status -> Compruebas que está todo correctamente

Y ya por manía puedes hacer un:

- Git log -> Para comprobar que está correctamente comiteado lo que has
  pusheado

Para salir de Git log, pulsa "Q"

Conforme pase el tiempo te acostumbrarás

Comment: Intenté con `git pull` pero me salía error(_fatal: refusing to merge unrelated histories_). Muchas gracias por la metodología, la tomaré mucho en cuenta, en especial por `git fetch`.

Comment: Cuidado con el git push -f, ya que es forzar. En este caso no tenías opción supongo, pero no es una buena práctica ;)

Comment: si ya se que es un riesgo hacer git push -f pero no me quedó de otra :(

Answer (score 2):

Antes de hacer `git push` siempre pero siempre debes hacer `git pull`, si en caso hay algun conflicto debes arreglarlos manualmente, y esos archivos que tienen conflicto debes adicionarlos nuevamente.